# Configuração de validação em campos dinâmicos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validação

Tenho um problema que é o seguinte, tenho os campos: Nome, Idade e Texto;

Em uma parte do sistema eu cadastro que o campo Texto só vai aparecer se o campo Nome for igual a `PH` e o campo Idade ter o valor `20` com as duas condições verdadeiras eu libero então o campo Texto.

A minha dificuldade nessa parte é porque pode ter muitos campos porque o formulário é montado pelo cliente, ou seja, o cliente pode cadastrar 20, 30 campos pra esse formulário e todos terem uma regra especifica pra liberar algum outro campo. Existe algum plugin que verifique ou que faz esse tipo de validação?

Nesse momento eu tentei o seguinte, porém só valida dessa forma se fosse de 1 para 1. Mas nesse caso pode ser de `N-1` ou `1-N` ou seria melhor criar uma tabela intermediária para tal ação?

```
$(function () {
    var campoDependente = '#codigo_<?php echo $condicao->atividade_campo_dependente ?>',
            campoTrigger = '#codigo_<?php echo $condicao->atividade_campo ?>',
            valor = '<?php echo trim($condicao->condicao) ?>';


    function mostrar() {

        var val = '';
        var checkbox = $(campoTrigger + ' input:checked');
        var select = $(campoTrigger + ' select > option:selected');
        var input = $(campoTrigger + ' input');

        if (checkbox.length > 0) {
            val = $.trim(checkbox.parent().text());

        } else if (select.length > 0) {
            val = $.trim(select.text());

        } else {
            val = input.val();

        }

        if (val == valor) {
            $(campoDependente).css('display', 'inline-block');
        } else {
            $(campoDependente).css('display', 'none');
        }

    }

    mostrar();
    $(campoTrigger).change(mostrar);

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tens de criar uma lógica de verificações. Podes fazer isso num objeto com regras de verificação. Cada chave poderia ser o `name` ou `id`  do input que aparecerá se algumas regras forem verificadas. Dessa maneira haverá uma estrutura que facilmente se monta com JS.

Exemplo da ideia:

```
var regras = {
    texto: {
        nome: 'PH',
        idade: 20
    }
};
```

e depois um código que fosse procurar regras e elementos DOM para e verificar tudo:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', verificador);
}

function procurador(chave, objeto) {
    if (chave in objeto) return chave;
    var match = Object.keys(objeto).filter(function (key) {
        var subObjeto = objeto[key];
        if (typeof subObjeto != 'object') return false;
        return procurador(chave, subObjeto);
    })[0];
    return match;
}

function verificador() {
    var prop = this.name; // saber qual input recebeu keyup
    if (!prop) return;    // caso não tenha nome interromper
        Object.keys(regras).forEach(function (regra) { // iterar as regras
        var regrasLocais = Object.keys(regras[regra]); // regras a cumprir
        var target = document.querySelector('[name="' + regra + '"');
        var valores = regrasLocais.map(function (nome) { // mapear regras com o input respetivo guardando o seu valor
            return document.querySelector('[name="' + nome + '"').value;
        });
        var valida = valores.filter(function (value, i) { // verificar quais inputs têm o valor == ao que é esperado pela regra
            var original = regras[regra][regrasLocais[i]];
            return value == original;
        });
        if (valida.length == regrasLocais.length) target.classList.remove('invalido'); // se todas as verificações tiverem passado
        else target.classList.add('invalido'); // caso falhe a validação
    });
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vazuLkf0/1/

**Um exemplo mais complexo** com funções dentro de regras de verificação seria: http://jsfiddle.net/vazuLkf0/5/

Demorou-me um pouco a fazer este código. Achei a pergunta e o problema interessante então [coloquei no github](https://goo.gl/5Gv8XG) também.
Espero ser isto que procuras :)

Comment: Só mais uma coisinha que não citei e quando os campos não são apenas input's tentei colocar aqui na variável **valores** na função verificador tentei agrupar os seletores porém sem sucesso por exemplo tenho campos que são selects nesse caso preciso do .text e não do .value como faria nesse caso ? meio que pegar o texto dos campos universalmente e ficou bom o codigo boa iniciativa de coloca-lo no github

Comment: @PauloHenrique e nesse caso as `option` têm `value`? se não tiverem value o `select.value` retorna o texto/`.innerHTML`

Comment: nesse caso os options tem value sim, exemplo: o `sim` tem valor `27` os numeros nos values são representados os ID no banco de dados, caso o cliente selecionar um deles eu tenho que salvar no banco e depois trazer marcado o valor respectivo e o `.innerHTML` por algum motivo trás o input como vazio mesmo preenchido.