# Configuração de validação em campos dinâmicos com grupos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Cenário: O cliente hoje tem um lugar no sistema, especifico para cadastrar campos pra um processo que será automatizado esses campos que são cadastrados podem ser (selects, checkbox, radio, textarea e text) logo em seguida o cliente pode cadastrar os campos ligados a uma atividade desse processo por exemplo atividade verificar documentação tem os campos: campo_1(select), campo_2(text)
e nesses campos são atribuídos condições de liberação; para liberar o campo_1 no formulário da atividade o campo_2 tem que ter o valor X

Estou com um problema que é o seguinte, tenho uma validação de campos que é responsável para liberar outros campos, tem um tópico que foi respondido pra essa situação que dará uma base bem concreta do que estou falando

[Configuração de validação em campos dinâmicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65284/configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-campos-din%C3%A2micos)

porém agora surgiu a necessidade da mesma ideia só que para grupos condicionais por exemplo:

**grupo 1** 
(campo_1 = "PH" , campo_2 = 3, campo_3 = 4)

**grupo 2**
(campo_1 = "PH", campo_2 = 3, campo_3 = `5`)

notamos acima que a unica diferença entre os dois grupos é o campo_3 que esta com o valor 5 no grupo dois, ficando a seguinte condição

`grupo 1 [OR || AND] grupo 2 libera campo_4`

Pra essa situação citada utilizamos o operador OR. Nesse caso estamos nos referenciando que o campo_4 só será liberado caso os campos pertencentes ao grupo 1 tenham os valores `"PH", 3, 4` OU o grupo 2 tenha os valores  `"PH", 3, 5` atendendo uma das regras citadas pelo grupo o campo_4 é liberado nesse formulário.

Utilizo hoje o seguinte código para a liberação dos campos.

```
function iniciaVerificador<?= $i ?>(atividade_campo, atividade_campo_dependente, codigo, regras){
    var campoDependente = '#codigo_'+ atividade_campo_dependente;
    var campoTrigger = '#codigo_'+ atividade_campo;
    var codigoCampo = '#codigo_'+ codigo;

    var checkbox = $(campoTrigger + ' input:checked');
    var select = $(campoTrigger + ' select > option:selected');
    var input = $(campoTrigger + ' input');
    var textarea = $(campoTrigger + ' textarea');


    if (checkbox.length > 0) {
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#codigo_'+atividade_campo+' input[type="radio"], #codigo_'+atividade_campo+' input[type="checkbox"]');
    } else if (select.length > 0) {
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#codigo_'+atividade_campo+' select');
    } else if(input.length > 0) {
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#codigo_'+atividade_campo+' input');
    } else {
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#codigo_'+atividade_campo+' textarea');
    }

    $(inputs).on('change', function(){
        verificador<?= $i ?>(regras, checkbox,select,input,textarea);
    });
    $(inputs).on('keyup', function(){
        verificador<?= $i ?>(regras, checkbox,select,input,textarea);
    });

    verificador<?= $i ?>(regras, checkbox,select,input,textarea);

}

function verificador<?= $i ?>(regras, checkbox,select,input,textarea) {
    Object.keys(regras).forEach(function (regra) { // iterar as regras que foram atribuidas na variavel regras

        var regrasLocais = Object.keys(regras[regra]); // regras que tem que cumprir pra liberação
        var target = $('[id="' + regra + '"]'); //Tragetoria da regra, nesse caso div
        var valores = regrasLocais.map(function (nome) { // mapear regras com o input respectivo guardando o seu valor

            if (checkbox.length > 0) {
                var input_text = $('[id="'+ nome +'"] input[type="radio"], [id="'+ nome +'"] input[type="checkbox"]');

                if(input_text.length > 0) {
                    var array_check = [];
                    for (var ck=0; ck < input_text.length; ck++) {
                        if(input_text[ck].checked){
                            array_check.push(input_text[ck].value);
                        }
                    }
                    return array_check.join();
                }
            }

            var input_text = $('[id="'+ nome +'"] input, [id="'+ nome +'"] select > option:checked, [id="'+ nome +'"] input:checked, [id="'+ nome +'"] textarea ');

            if(input_text.length > 0) {
                var value = [];
                input_text.each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(':checked') || $(this).is(':selected') || $(this).is(':text') || $(this).is('textarea')){
                        value.push($(this).val());

                        if($(this).is(':selected')){
                            value.push('select');
                        }

                    }
                });

                return value.join();
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        });

        var valida = valores.filter(function (value, i) { // verificar quais inputs têm o valor == ao que é esperado pela regra
            var original = regras[regra][regrasLocais[i]];
            var arrsplint = value.split(",");
            var arrOriginal = original.split(",");

            if($.inArray('select',arrsplint, 0) != -1){
                var removeItem = 'select';
                var arrsplint = $.grep(arrsplint, function(valueArr) {
                    return valueArr != removeItem;
                });

                var removeItem = '';
                var arrsplint = $.grep(arrsplint, function(valueArr) {
                    return valueArr != removeItem;
                });



                var arrsplint = arrsplint.join();
                var count = 0;
                var returnValue = [];

                arrOriginal.forEach(function (valueOriginal) {

                    if(arrsplint == valueOriginal){
                        returnValue[count] = true;
                    } else {
                        returnValue[count] = false;
                    }

                    count++;
                });

                if($.inArray(true,returnValue, 0) != -1){
                    return 1;
                }else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            return value.toUpperCase() == original.toUpperCase();
        });

        if (valida.length == regrasLocais.length) {
            target.removeClass('invalido'); // se todas as verificações tiverem passado
            target.removeAttr("style");

            target.addClass('corfundo');
            target.removeClass('mudacor');

            var x = 0;
            var clear = setInterval(function(){

                target.addClass('mudacor');
                target.removeClass('corfundo');

                if (++x === 1) {
                    window.clearInterval(clear);
                }
            }, 1000);


        } else {
            target.addClass('invalido'); // caso falhe a validação
            target.val('');
            target.prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    var regras = {
        <?= $condicaoRegra; ?>
    };
    iniciaVerificador<?= $i ?>(<?php echo $condicaoCampo->atividade_campo ?>, <?php echo $condicaoCampo->atividade_campo_dependente ?>, <?php echo $condicaoCampo->codigo ?>, regras );
});
```

Hoje essa regra funciona perfeitamente para campos `N-N` e especificamente para a condição AND, nessa nova necessidade agora precisa que seja atribuído também tanto a condição AND como a OR e que seja atendido por grupos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conseguir resolver a pergunta, ela será nas regras devemos colocar a seguinte condição para o objeto

```
var objRegras = {1:{campo_4:{campo_2: "PH"}}, 2:{campo_4:{campo_2: "KM"}}};
```

Onde é seguido de grupos o campo que vai ser liberado e em seguida os campos que devem ser preenchidos para liberar o campo informado.

tento o objeto de regras basta agora pecorrer o objeto e armazenar os valores que serão digitados para verificar se é real nesse caso o campo_2 recebendo PH ou KM será liberado o campo_4 então pra essa situação temos que verificar em cada laço se a condição aplicada é verdadeira então criamos um objeto para armazenar as condições, guardando `true` OR `false`
e em seguida realizo um `.join` e um `.replace` para trocando toda as (virgulas) que são geradas pelo `.join` pelas condições que queremos realizar, nessa situação foi relacionado a condição `OR` depois de montar ficaria da seguinte forma `true || false`  então agora basta apenas colocamos essa condição dentro de um `eval()` onde o eval ele executa uma string como uma condição. segue o codigo. com as renovações dos laços.

```
$(function () {
    //adiciono as regras.
    var regras = <?= $condicaoRegra; ?>;
    //inicio a função para verificar os campos
    iniciaVerificadorGrupo<?= $i ?>(<?php echo $condicaoCampo->atividade_campo ?>, <?php echo $condicaoCampo->atividade_campo_dependente ?>, <?php echo $condicaoCampo->codigo ?>, regras, <?php echo $condicaoCampo->grupo; ?> );
 });


          //funçao relacionada para iniciar o verificador, pegando os tipos de campos (select,checkbox,radio,textarea,input)
function iniciaVerificadorGrupo<?= $i ?>(atividade_campo, atividade_campo_dependente, codigo, regras, grupo){
var campoDependente = '#codigo_'+ atividade_campo_dependente;
var campoTrigger = '#codigo_'+ atividade_campo;
var codigoCampo = '#codigo_'+ codigo;

var checkbox = $(campoTrigger + ' input:checked');
var select = $(campoTrigger + ' select > option:selected');
var input = $(campoTrigger + ' input');
var textarea = $(campoTrigger + ' textarea');

if (checkbox.length > 0) {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#codigo_'+atividade_campo+' input[type="radio"], #codigo_'+atividade_campo+' input[type="checkbox"]');
} else if (select.length > 0) {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#codigo_'+atividade_campo+' select');
} else if(input.length > 0) {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#codigo_'+atividade_campo+' input');
} else {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#codigo_'+atividade_campo+' textarea');
}


$(inputs).on('change', function(){

    var campoDependente = '#codigo_'+ atividade_campo_dependente;
    var campoTrigger = '#codigo_'+ atividade_campo;
    var codigoCampo = '#codigo_'+ codigo;

    var checkbox = $(campoTrigger + ' input:checked');
    var select = $(campoTrigger + ' select > option:selected');
    var input = $(campoTrigger + ' input');
    var textarea = $(campoTrigger + ' textarea');

    verificadorGrupo<?= $i ?>(regras, checkbox,select,input,textarea,grupo);
});

$(inputs).on('keyup', function(){

    var campoDependente = '#codigo_'+ atividade_campo_dependente;
    var campoTrigger = '#codigo_'+ atividade_campo;
    var codigoCampo = '#codigo_'+ codigo;

    var checkbox = $(campoTrigger + ' input:checked');
    var select = $(campoTrigger + ' select > option:selected');
    var input = $(campoTrigger + ' input');
    var textarea = $(campoTrigger + ' textarea');

    verificadorGrupo<?= $i ?>(regras, checkbox,select,input,textarea,grupo);
});

verificadorGrupo<?= $i ?>(regras, checkbox,select,input,textarea,grupo);

}

//executa o verificador do grupo, onde fica as questões para liberar os campos ou não
function verificadorGrupo<?= $i ?>(regras, checkbox,select,input,textarea,grupo) {

var mapCondicao = new Array(regras.length);
var retornaCondicaoUnica = new Array();
var valores;
var valida;
var interetor = 0;
var keyCampoDependente;
var target;
var regraVariosElementosPertecentesAUmGrupo = new Array();
var posElementoPrincipal;


//pecorro as regras com o map
$.map(regras, function(regra,keyR){

    //realizo um for de regra para pegar os valores das condições
    for(var key in regra){

        keyCampoDependente = Object.keys(regra[key]);//pego as chaves
        target = $('[id="' + key + '"]'); //qual campo vai ser liberado
        valores = keyCampoDependente.map(function (nome) {

            if (checkbox.length > 0) {
                var input_text = $('[id="'+ nome +'"] input[type="radio"], [id="'+ nome +'"] input[type="checkbox"]');

                if(input_text.length > 0) {
                    var array_check = [];
                    for (var ck=0; ck < input_text.length; ck++) {
                        if(input_text[ck].checked){
                            array_check.push(input_text[ck].value);
                        }
                    }
                    return array_check.join();
                }
            }

            var input_text = $('[id="'+ nome +'"] input, [id="'+ nome +'"] select > option:checked, [id="'+ nome +'"] input:checked, [id="'+ nome +'"] textarea ');

            if(input_text.length > 0) {
                var value = [];
                input_text.each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(':checked') || $(this).is(':selected') || $(this).is(':text') || $(this).is('textarea')){
                        value.push($(this).val());

                        //verifico se esta selecionado caso esteja selecionado adiciono no array o 'select'
                        if($(this).is(':selected')){
                            value.push('select');
                        }
                    }
                });

                //retorno os valores com join para separar todos por virgula
                return value.join();
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        });


        //crio array para a condição
        var retornaCondicao = [];

        //realizo um filtro de valores
        valida = valores.filter(function (value, i) {

            //pego o valor original da regra, o que eu preciso para liberar o campo
            var original = regra[key][keyCampoDependente[i]];
            var arrsplint = value.split(",");
            var arrOriginal = original.split(",");

            //verifico valor select
            if($.inArray('select',arrsplint, 0) != -1){
                var removeItem = 'select';

                //removo o valor select
                var arrsplint = $.grep(arrsplint, function(valueArr) {
                    return valueArr != removeItem;
                });

                //removo vazio caso exista
                var removeItem = '';
                var arrsplint = $.grep(arrsplint, function(valueArr) {
                    return valueArr != removeItem;
                });

                //dou um join com os valores
                var arrsplint = arrsplint.join();
                var count = 0;
                var returnValue = [];

                //pego o valor orginal pecorro os dados para guardar se os valores estão iguais para retornar true
                arrOriginal.forEach(function (valueOriginal) {
                    if(arrsplint == valueOriginal){
                        returnValue[count] = true;
                    } else {
                        returnValue[count] = false;
                    }
                    count++;
                });


                if($.inArray(true,returnValue, 0) != -1){
                    retornaCondicao[[keyR],[i]] = 1;
                    return 1;
                }else {
                    retornaCondicao[[keyR],[i]] = 0;
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            if(value.toUpperCase() == original.toUpperCase()){
                retornaCondicao[[keyR],[i]] = 1;
                return true;
            } else {
                retornaCondicao[[keyR],[i]] = 0;
                return false;
            }
        });


        if($.inArray(0,retornaCondicao, 0) != -1){
            retornaCondicaoUnica[interetor] = false;
            interetor = interetor + 1;
        } else {
            retornaCondicaoUnica[interetor] = retornaCondicao;
            interetor = interetor + 1;
        }
    }
});

retornaCondicaoUnica.forEach(function(elemento, pos){
    if(retornaCondicaoUnica[pos] !== false){
        posElementoPrincipal = pos;
        for(var posEle in elemento){
            if(elemento[posEle] == 1){
                regraVariosElementosPertecentesAUmGrupo[posEle] = true;
            } else {
                regraVariosElementosPertecentesAUmGrupo[posEle] = false;
            }
        }
    }
});

if($.inArray(false,regraVariosElementosPertecentesAUmGrupo, 0) != -1){
    retornaCondicaoUnica[posElementoPrincipal] = false;
} else {
    retornaCondicaoUnica[posElementoPrincipal] = true;
}

var ret = replaceAll(retornaCondicaoUnica.join(), ',', ' || ');

if (eval(ret)) {
    target.removeClass('invalido'); // se todas as verificações tiverem passado
    target.removeAttr("style");

    target.addClass('corfundo');
    target.removeClass('mudacor');

    var x = 0;
    var clear = setInterval(function(){

        target.addClass('mudacor');
        target.removeClass('corfundo');

        if (++x === 1) {
            window.clearInterval(clear);
        }
    }, 1000);
} else {
    target.addClass('invalido'); // caso falhe a validação
}
                                }
```